# Matlab: find inner boundary of set of vertices

Tags: matlab, draw, vertices

I have a set of (x,y) points defined in the following way:

```
    map=[0,0;66,0;66,44;44,44;44,66;110,66;110,110;0,110];
```

There is then a function that connects these points (which are vertices, i.e. corner points) together to form a closed shape. The example vertices I have given form a shape something like this:

```
     ________________________________________
    |                                        |
    |                                        |
    |                                        |
    |                    ____________________|
    |                   |
    |                   |_______
    |                           |
    |                           |
    |                           |
    |                           |
    |___________________________|
```

I would like to now automatically generate a second set of vertices that form a boundary inside the shape, offset by some amount. I.e. this:

```
    inner_boundary=[5,5;61,5;61,39;39,39;39,71;105,71;105,105;5,105];
     ________________________________________
    |   ___________________________________  |
    |  |                                   | |
    |  |              _____________________| |
    |  |             |   ____________________|
    |  |             |  |
    |  |             |  |_______
    |  |             |________  |
    |  |                      | |
    |  |                      | |
    |  |______________________| |
    |___________________________|
```

Any ideas on how to do this? I've been racking my brains but can't think of a robust way to do this. I need it to **automatically** do this for any input set of vertices. Also, to clarify - I am just interested in how to specify the set of vertices, not the drawing part.

Many thanks!

Comment: please clarify what should happen in the case, that the original boundary is too slim to put a smaller one inside. Means the distance between two vertices is smaller than `2*offset`.

Comment: and: do you have the image processing toolbox?

Comment: I would like to stop and throw up an error if the distance between sides is too small to fit a boundary inside.

Comment: I think I do have the image processing toolbox, yes. However, I am not sure if other machines on which I would like this to run do - so if there is away to avoid using it then that would be preferable.

Comment: Given a clockwise/counterclockwise ordering of points, you could use my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23543212/defining-an-inside-room-point-from-wall-points/23548238#23548238).

Comment: Ah brilliant! That's a great way of doing it! Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution based on Image Processing Toolbox functions. The basic idea is as follows:

1. Use "poly2mask" to create a BW (0-1) image from the polygon
   coordinates
2. Use "imerode" to erode the mask by 1 pixel
3. Use "bwboundaries" to trace the new, eroded, boundary

Code example:

```
x = [4 10 10 4 4];
y = [4 4 10 10 4];
mask = poly2mask(x,y,12,12);
mask_eroded = imerode(mask, 1);
newBnds = bwboundaries(mask_eroded);
newBnds = newBnds{1};
```

Note that the newBnds will probably contain more points than you want because it traces every single pixel on the boundary. You can write a simple iterative routine to discard non-endpoints.

Comment: Nice solution. I'd only suggest you create a structuring element to do the erosion all at once rather than use a loop. For example, to erode 5 pixels, use `r=5; se = strel('square',2*r+1); mask_eroded = imerode(mask, se);`.

Comment: thanks for your solution as well. if other people look at this who are able to use the image processing toolbox then this looks like an easy way to do it. since I'm not sure all the PC's on which I would like this to work have the toolbox, I will go with beaker's suggestion above. but thanks!